# How to change position of SetError EditText

Tags: android, email, android-edittext

Hi i'm trynig to set `setError` in my `Edittext` when user enter invalid email But I encountered a problem whit `setError` Following is the snapshot for better understanding  :

[image: Problem]

this is what i need

[image: solution]

```
<EditText
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hintemail"
            android:id="@+id/emailtext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_email"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

Custom Rounded EditText :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#f4f4f7" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="34dp">
    <!-- left is icon size + 2x side padding around icon-->
    <!-- 18 + 8 + 8 -->
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp"
            android:topRightRadius="6dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#BBBBBB" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: you can use android:paddingRight="5dp"

Comment: @tahsinRupam works fine thanks man